# How to show group by data just like sample image using Chart.js?

Tags: chart.js

[image]

I need to generate this kind of chart, I am trying using chart.js.
I am able to plot the dots (here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nakul89/rL9ob80f/1/)) below is the output of it

[image]

Also need to add two horizontal lines into it, But not able to proceed further. Is it possible to generate this kind of chart in chart.js ? If yes please let me know how i can achieve that? If no then is it possible using high charts or any other library?

```html
 <html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.min.js"></script> 
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
    <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
    </div>

    <script>
      var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
      var options = {
    scales: {
        xAxes: [{offset:true,
            gridLines: {
          offsetGridLines: true
        }
        }],
        yAxes: [{
            gridLines: {
          drawBorder: false
        }
        }],
    },
};
      var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
          type: 'line',
          options: options,
          data: {
            labels: ["05/05/2021", "06/05/2021"],
            datasets: [{ 
                data: [49,51],
                label: "AM",
                borderColor: "#3e95cd",
                backgroundColor: "rgb(62,149,205)",
                borderWidth:2,
                type: 'line',
                fill:false,showLine: false
              }, { 
                data: [47,48],
                label: "PM",
                borderColor: "#3cba9f",
                backgroundColor: "#3cba9f",
                borderWidth:2,showLine: false
              }, { 
                data: [50,52],
                label: "Night",
                borderColor: "#ffa500",
                backgroundColor:"#ffa500",
                borderWidth:2,showLine: false
              }            
            ]
          },         
        });
    </script>   
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a second `x` axis that shows the date and empty labels for the other spaces, then you can use `null` values in your data array to make the data points appear in the right spots.

Example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Chart.js Mixed Chart</title>
  <!--Chart.js JS CDN-->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div>
    <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
  </div>

  <script>
    var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: 'line',
      data: {
        labels: ["PM", "AM", "Night", "PM", "AM", "Night"],
        datasets: [{
            data: [null, 49, null, null, 51],
            label: "AM",
            borderColor: "#3e95cd",
            backgroundColor: "rgb(62,149,205)",
            borderWidth: 2,
            type: 'line',
            fill: false,
            showLine: false
          }, {
            data: [47, null, null, 48],
            label: "PM",
            borderColor: "#3cba9f",
            backgroundColor: "#3cba9f",
            borderWidth: 2,
            showLine: false
          }, {
            data: [null, null, 50, null, null, 52],
            label: "Night",
            borderColor: "#ffa500",
            backgroundColor: "#ffa500",
            borderWidth: 2,
            showLine: false
          }

        ]
      },
      options: {
        scales: {
          xAxes: [{},
            {
              id: 'dates',
              type: 'category',
              position: 'bottom',
              labels: ["", "05/05/2021", "", "", "06/05/2021", ""]
            }
          ]
        }
      }

    });
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Leelenaleee/4tx2swmr/1/

Comment: Thanks for your inputs @LeeLenalee. I added horizontal lines using plugin ([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nakul89/koyrLtnw/2/)) but once I add code for 2nd x-axis then nothing works it goes back to normal graph ([2nd jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nakul89/sdeq2myp/5/)). One notable difference is I am using v2.9.4 and yours is v3.3.0. When I change cdn or add 3.3.0 resource it throws error.

Comment: Mb noticed answer was also full of junk, updated it, clean and in V2